# Create Windows Print Driver

Tags: c#, c++, windows, printing

i'm searching the net to solve this problem but i still don't have any clue how it will be done, or ***IF*** it ***CAN*** be done.
I'll be more specific.

I need to create a custom Windows Printer Driver (i think for windows 7 and above) which will execute a simple task. This driver doesn't interface with any device but have to execute a command (launch a .exe located in a specific file system path). 
Is it possible to create such "fake" driver and let windows recognise like as installed printer (for example showing the device in the printer list while printing a document).

I'm familiar with c++ and my .exe is written in c# . I will explain and answer to any clarification the community need to help me solving this issue.